# Referencing Checkboxes within a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a `Repeater` control that is creating a dynamic amount of `CheckBoxList` controls and each list has a different set of `ListItems`.

I have done this part just fine, but the issue I'm having is how to save the checked states of these dynamically created boxes. I cannot find out how to get the list of these `CheckBoxList` controls.

Here's some pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (Item i in MyRepeater)
{
    if (i.ItemType is CheckBoxList)
    {
        foreach (ListItem x in i)
        {
            update table set tiChecked = x.Checked
            where table.id = i.id and table.typeid = x.id
        }
    }
}
```

I have the ID of the `CheckBoxList` and the `ListItem` corresponding to the IDs in the DB.

**Edit:**

Of course after I ask, I find it out. This seems to be getting me what I want

```
foreach (RepeaterItem tmp in rptReportList.Items)
{
    if (tmp.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        foreach (Control c in tmp.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBoxList)
            {
                DisplayMessage(this, c.ID.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working?  The foreach(ListItem x in i)?

Comment: It's just pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do. The items returned by MyRepeater are just RepeaterItems. Those Items don't seem to have any sub-items, so I can't figure out how to enumerate my CheckBoxLists.

Comment: I was going to say, I think if you took the approach of your psuedo code, that you would have to cast i as CheckBoxList...  so foreach(ListItem x in (i as CheckBoxList).Items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look deeper than the `RepeaterItem`:

```
// repeater item
foreach (Control cr in MyRepeater.Controls)
{
    // controls within repeater item
    foreach (Control c in cr.Controls)
    {
        CheckBoxList chklst = c as CheckBoxList;
        if (chklst != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem i in chklst.Items)
            {
                string valueToUpdate = i.Value;
                string textToUpdate = i.Text;
                bool checkedToUpdate = i.Selected;

                // Do update
            }
        }
    }
}
```